# Adding AngularJS to dynamic form in OrchardCMS site

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms-1.9

I would like to add AngularJS to the dynamic forms in my OrchardCMS website (v.1.9.3.0). Instructions describing how I created these forms are described in the following link:
http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Creating-Dynamic-Forms/

I'm surprised no one in the OrchardCMS community has documented how to accomplish this. The closest thing I found was an AngularJS presentation at an OrchardCMS conference; see below:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eu8ixE_ZOLM

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

I found this [Orchard.AngularJS](https://github.com/kroonwijk/Orchard.AngularJS) module. It supports currently the latest Orchard CMS v1.10.1, but unfortunatelly there is no documentation how to use it. I wish somebody could share some bits of his/her experience how to effectively use AngularJS to develop Orchard CMS modules and themes, as I'm new to Orchard CMS as well.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes